# What does state mean in unwinding?

Tags: x86, seh, msvc

I'm looking at `UnwindMapEntry`. Here is it's declaration:

```
//
// UnwindMapEntry - Description of each state transition for unwinding
//  the stack (i.e. calling destructors).
//
// The unwind map is an array, indexed by current state.  Each entry specifies
// the state to go to during unwind, and the action required to get there.
// Note that states are represented by a signed integer, and that the 'blank'
// state is -1 so that the array remains 0-based (because by definition there
// is never any unwind action to be performed from state -1).  It is also
// assumed that state indices will be dense, i.e. that there will be no gaps of
// unused state indices in a function.
//

typedef const struct _s_UnwindMapEntry {
    __ehstate_t toState;                    // State this action takes us to
#if _EH_RELATIVE_FUNCINFO
    int         action;                     // Image relative offset of funclet
#else
    void        (__cdecl * action)(void);   // Funclet to call to effect state change
#endif
} UnwindMapEntry;
```

Sorry if it's obvious for you but what does toState means? It is not clear for me by reading the description above.

Also there is this structure for a tryblockmaprntry which is also involved somehow:

```
//
// HandlerMapEntry - associates a handler list (sequence of catches) with a
//  range of eh-states.
//
typedef const struct _s_TryBlockMapEntry {
    __ehstate_t     tryLow;             // Lowest state index of try
    __ehstate_t     tryHigh;            // Highest state index of try
    __ehstate_t     catchHigh;          // Highest state index of any associated catch
    //....
```

What's `catchHigh` - is it always `tryHigh + 1`?

OK It seems the `catchHigh` is continuing the state inside the catch block - because you can have exception there too. But still I don't see it's purpose - like when this field makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

the *__ehstate_t* type is defined as *int*. *toState* is the index of the next handler in the array that needs to be unwind.

*Action* is the operation that needs to be done in order to reach the next state (the value of *toState*). This happens until *toState* reaches -1, which is the "blank" state that ends the unwinding process.

The state is incremented by one every time you enter a try block or otherwise create an object that must be destructed in the unwinding process if an exception is thrown before the program called its destructor.

Example:

Say there is a function `int F1(){}`

At the beginning of the function, the *state* for the current scope is -1 as there are no actions to take if an exception occurs.

Somewhere after the beginning of F1 an object of type ClassA is created. This calls the constructor `ClassA::ClassA()`. At this point if an exception is thrown, there is a ClassA object that needs to be deleted before the `catch` block is called. The initialization of the object incremented the *state* to 0.

Now comes a `try` block - the state is now 1. Should an exception be thrown here, the handler will have to leave the `try` block (state->0) and call `ClassA::~ClassA()` on the object that was created before (state->-1). If the execution reaches the end of the `try` block an no exception occurred, the state is decremented (state->0 again).

*tryLow* is the target outmost state that a handler must get to before it calls the `catch` block. In our example, when entering the `try` block (state = 1), the *tryLow* value will be -1. The handler will have to get to state -1, that is, leaving the `try` block *and* calling `ClassA::~ClassA()` and only then call the `catch` block.

For reverse engineering purposes, there is a great post at OpenRCE:

http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example algorithm of how it's done. Also if possible to include `tryLow`, `tryLow` and `catchHigh`. In the meantime I'll be continuing to try to understand this myself by looking into the msvct crt sources.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Also there is sometime a filler of `UnwindMapEntry <-1, 0>` - any ideas what that is for?

Comment: @rec: that's for empty transitions in the state machine (nothing to destruct).

Comment: I guess this is a representation of the relevant UnwindMapEntry with a *toState* (-1) and an *action* function pointer (NULL).